# Serving static page from custom scala action in Play Framework

Tags: java, scala, playframework, securesocial

I'm new to scala, but have some experience using the play framework in Java. I've added the SecureSocial authentication library, which defines a SecuredACtion, and it seems to be working correctly. However, I'm having trouble understanding the expected content within the custom action in scala code.

Here's my controllers class. Ideally, "index" would simply redirect the authenticated request to "unprotectedIndex" somehow, but that doesn't seem to be possible. So if not, next best thing is simply to serve the file directly from inside of the secured action, but that's also not working.

What is missing from my code?

```
object Application extends Controller with securesocial.core.SecureSocial {
  // this doesn't compile, but it's a long scala exception that I don't know how to fix.
  def index = SecuredAction { implicit request =>
    Assets.at("/public", "index.html").apply(request) 
  }

  def unprotectedIndex = Assets.at("/public", "index.html")

}
```

It seems like it's expecting a SimpleResult but getting a Future[SimpleResult] - this feels like it shouldn't be complicated, but what am I missing?

Comment: Please see my edit as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are using play framework 2.2. There were some changes and most methods return `Future[SimpleResult]` instead of just `Result` or `SimpleResult`. You can check if you are able to do like this: `def index = SecuredAction.async {...}` (but I'm almost sure you can't).

You can use this approach to make it work correctly:

```
import scala.concurrent.Await
import scala.concurrent.duration._

def index = SecuredAction { implicit request =>
  Await.result(Assets.at("/public", "index.html").apply(request), 5 seconds) //you can specify you maximum wait time here
}
```

**EDIT**

Even one more thing to simplify:

```
Await.result(unprotectedIndex(request), 5 seconds)
```

So you can call your `unprotectedIndex` from your `index` Action

Comment: Cool, thanks. That makes so much more sense than .value.get.get as I had discovered.

Comment: So, actually SecuredAction.async worked just fine. It accepted the Future in the block, rather than having to put in any Await calls or whatever else. Perfect.

Comment: Oh, that's good. I just wasn't sure of how SecuredAction is implemented so assumed it's just an Action

Answer (score 0):

So, just by looking at syntax highlighting in my IDE I have been able to get something that seems to compile and work but looks deeply wrong to me.

I changed it to this:

```
def index = SecuredAction { implicit request =>
    Assets.at("/public", "index.html").apply(request).value.get.get
  }
```

Is that the correct way to do this? It looks really weird to me, am I just not familiar with the idioms?

Comment: You're calling `value` on a `Future` which returns an `Option[Try[T]]` where `T` is generic (in this case a `Result` or one of its subtypes).  This is likely to result in `NoSuchElementException` since you're trying to get the value of a `Future` immediately rather than within a callback or one of its monadic functions like `map` or `flatMap`.